# unable to config certbot with nginx to accept https

Tags: ssl, nginx, dns, certbot

When I tried to configure my nginx app with certboot following [this tutorial](https://manual.seafile.com/deploy/https_with_nginx.html) and others like. I allways step with the same amswer from certbot

> Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log Plugins
>   selected: Authenticator nginx, Installer nginx Obtaining a new
>   certificate Performing the following challenges: http-01 challenge for
>   sicocme.enterpriserealdomain.com http-01 challenge for
>   www.sicocme.enterpriserealdomain.com Waiting for verification...
>   Cleaning up challenges Failed authorization procedure.
>   sicocme.enterpriserealdomain.com (http-01):
>   urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect
>   to the client to verify the domain :: dns :: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN
>   looking up A for sicocme.enterpriserealdomain.com,
>   www.sicocme.enterpriserealdomain.com (http-01):
>   urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect
>   to the client to verify the domain :: dns :: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN
>   looking up A for www.sicocme.enterpriserealdomain.com
>
> IMPORTANT NOTES:
>    - The following errors were reported by the server:
>
> Domain: sicocme.enterpriserealdomain.com    Type:   connection
>   Detail: dns :: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for
>   sicocme.enterpriserealdomain.com
>
> Domain: www.sicocme.enterpriserealdomain.com    Type:   connection 
>   Detail: dns :: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for
>   www.sicocme.enterpriserealdomain.com
>
> To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
>   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
>   contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
>   your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
>   firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
>   client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
>   that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.

When I check my domain server the A record is there for both www and no-www with the correct IP address. The server has access to network and can access or be accessed by IP or domain name which proves that the DNS domain recognizes this machine and exists

Also I make shure to allow the proper ports with ufw

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
5432/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5432/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Why could this be happening?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is the same issue but with the Apache 
[image]

check the A record has set with the server then

```
 sudo certbot --apache -d DOMAIN_WOTHOUT_WWW -d DOMAIN_WITH_WWW
```

Then it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your DNS records are not propagated yet. See below url - 
https://dnsmap.io/#A/sicocme.enterpriserealdomain.com

Make sure your DNS records are propagated all over than things should be fine.

Comment: My network is a private one. There is no intention to register this DNS server in a external provider. How can I check the propagation of the records on my network? This network is not exposed to the internet

Comment: certbot deploys letsencrypt certificate, which will require a verification of the owner of the domain. Currently it can do that using DNS record verification or a http challenge. In either case you need to verify that you own the domain.

Comment: but I don't know why is failing finding my DNS. What can I do in a case like this? How can I make letsencrypt  pass the DNS verification with a record or a http challenge locally?

Comment: you need to add DNS records for your domain to verify.

Comment: I already added an A and a CNAME record. when listening in port 80 I was able to access to my app like this `http://sicocme.enterpriserealdomain.com` . Is not that prove of the proper configuration of DNS? Do I need to add another kind of record. The hosts files was also updated to fit this config

Answer (score 0):

You should add a new DNS record for `www.yourdomain.com` (for www).

I think you have added only DNS record for '@'
please check this:
[image]