# How to setup nginx ssl - reverse proxy for my domain name - Google compute engine -lets encrypt

Tags: nginx, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to make my application secure - using letsencrypt certbot.

**Setup**:
Domain (named servers of cloud DNS) <---> Cloud DNS (acme challenge* ) <--> Compute Engine (nginx  and  spring boot)

- I have created  a certificate from a local machine and added CNAME acme challenge in CLoud DNS to test verification.

I have installed nginx on compute engine and setup redirection from nginx : 80 to springboot:8080

So http://externalip  **Works**

**Goal**:
I want SSL to make my domain name work. https://mydomain.co.uk .

There is OAuth2 so I need https

**Now**:
I am following [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04) to create certificate.

**I did not do** - "Step 3 — Allowing HTTPS Through the Firewall". is this required?

I am executing step 4

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d {mydomain.com} -d www.{mydomain.com}
```

**Error**:

```
s3@{myaccount}:~$ sudo certbot --nginx -d {mydomain}.co.uk -d www.{mydomain}.co.uk
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator nginx, Installer nginx
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for www.{mydomain}.co.uk
Using default address 80 for authentication.
Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Failed authorization procedure. www.{mydomain}.co.uk (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns :: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for www.{mydomain}.co.uk - check that a DNS record exists for this domain; DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up AAAA for www.{mydomain}.co.uk - check that a DNS record exists for this domain


IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: www.{mydomain}.co.uk
   Type:   None
   Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for www.{mydomain}.co.uk -
   check that a DNS record exists for this domain; DNS problem:
   NXDOMAIN looking up AAAA for www.{mydomain}.co.uk - check that a DNS
   record exists for this domain
```

**How can I make nginx / app SSL enabled?**

Please feel free to suggest better OOTB solution (less expensive)

**I want to be able to access my application using url https://mydomain**

Note: my Compute Engine VM only has IPV4 stack type

(other posts on similar topic are not having accepted answer - [unable to config certbot with nginx to accept https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55033949/unable-to-config-certbot-with-nginx-to-accept-https))

**EDIT**

I have created a brand new VM (compute engine) this time with ***dual stack***.

Installed nginx
Did exactly (almost except ufw bit) - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04#step-5-%E2%80%93-setting-up-server-blocks-(recommended)

and after confirming the above blog is ***working*** continued the below

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04

**Latest ERROR**

```
$ sudo certbot --nginx -d {mydomain}.co.uk -d www.{mydomain}.co.uk 
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator nginx, Installer nginx
Enter email address (used for urgent renewal and security notices)  (Enter 'c' to cancel): {mymail}@yahoo.co.uk


Please read the Terms of Service at https://letsencrypt.org/documents/LE-SA-v1.2-November-15-2017.pdf. You must agree in order to register with the ACME server. 
Do you agree?  (Y)es/(N)o: Y

- - - Would you be willing, once your first certificate is successfully issued, to share your email address with the Electronic Frontier Foundation, a founding partner of the Let's Encrypt project and the non-profit organization that develops Certbot? We'd like to send you email about our work encrypting the web, EFF news, campaigns, and ways to support digital freedom.

-- - - - - - - - (Y)es/(N)o: Y 
Account registered. 
Requesting a certificate for {mydomain}.co.uk and www.{mydomain}.co.uk
Performing the following challenges: http-01 challenge for {mydomain}.co.uk http-01 challenge for www.{mydomain}.co.uk
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain www.{mydomain}.co.uk http-01 challenge for www.{mydomain}.co.uk
Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: www.{mydomain}.co.uk
   Type:   dns
   Detail: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for www.{mydomain}.co.uk -    check that a DNS record exists for this domain;
           DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up AAAA for www.{mydomain}.co.uk - check that a DNS    record exists for this domain
```

I updated the IP address in A record, with a new static ip of this Compute Engine. Will this take time ?

I reiterate the setup:

Terminal (Compute Engine) ---> Google Domain (custom name servers) -----> Cloud DNS with A record (contains IP) CNAME (domain name) + acme challenge  created when testing from my laptop.

*If this (old test) acme challenge needs to be removed, then let me know please.*

Comment: What company did you buy the domain from? Did you log in there and choose a Nameserver, and make a CNAME record pointing to the domain, and also an A record pointing to the IP address?

Comment: Its google domains. I have setup google cloud dns - the NS entries are added in the google domain . CNAME  and A type created in Cloud DNS

Comment: If your domain is very new, Google can take 48 hours for the DNS information to be available. Sometimes longer.

Comment: Also in Google domains, the Name or Host box should be `www` and the data or value box should be `mydomain.co.uk`

Comment: There is a bullet point in the post. I used my laptop to verify the path letsencrypt <->  domain <- > cloudDNS . Now I want to run letsencrypt from Compute Engine where my application runs. Please also see the Notes. Its only ipv4 ,  + ufw not run (unsure what will it do to my Compute Engine).

Comment: I identified a silly mistake in CNAME value - I used https://{mydomain} instead of http://{mydomain} @Bman70 sorry for overlooking your earlier comment. My url was always https, as I was using it with Google App Engine.